# Why are some functions available only in F# script files, not in source files?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-scripting

I have noticed this a few times now.  An example of an offending function is `Array.take`.  In a script file I can write

```
[|1; 2; 4; 7; 6; 5|]
|> Array.take 3
|> Array.iter (printfn "%d")
```

and this works without a problem.  But if I try to use `Array.take` in an actual source file, I get the following error

```
[|1; 2; 4; 7; 6; 5|]
|> Array.take 3 // RED SQUIGGLY ERROR HERE
|> Array.iter (printfn "%d")
```

and the error message is:

> ```
> The value, constructor, namespace or type 'take' is not defined
> ```

So, what gives?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you're seeing this is due to different versions of F#.  There was an attempt to regularise a lot of the `List` `Seq` and `Array` functions in F# 4.0, see: https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Status

One of the functions that was added as part of that process was `Array.take`.

In F# interactive, no doubt you are using the latest version of F# but presumably you are not in your compiled project.

This could be because you haven't changed the version in the project settings or it could be because you have a nuget package attached your project which references a specific version of F# Core via nuget.

If you go to your project properties, you should see an a 'Target F# Runtime' setting, change this to F# 4.0.  If I remember correctly, a nuget reference to a specific F# Core version will prevent you from changing that setting, in which case you'll need to delete the reference to F# core and re-add the correct version as a reference from the list of assemblies.

Comment: the `Target F# Runtime` is set to `4.3.0.0` and is greyed out.  The project is using `version 4.3.0.0` of `FSharp.Core`.  In spite of that, I encounter the problem.

Comment: @Shredderroy F# Core 4.3.0.0 corresponds to F# 3.0.  F# 4.0 uses F# Core version 4.4.0.0.  Delete the reference to F# Core and re-add it from the list of `Extensions` assemblies.